# Is there any way to get proc/pid/status after termination or just before termination of the process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need to access proc/pid/status and get VmPeak for a process.For longer process I am able to get it using another thread but for small process I always get an error(no such process).Is there any way or workaround that I can use to get the job done.I am uisng python 2.7,so far I have done the following..

```
import os
import subprocess
import threading
from shutil import copyfile
import time

rp = None
br = 0
pid = -1


class MemoryThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global br, rp
        while br == 0:
            try:
                pid = rp.pid
            except Exception as e:
                pid = -1
            if not pid == -1:
                try:
                    pp = open("/proc/" + str(pid) + "/status")
                    st = "X"
                    for l in pp.readlines():
                        if l.startswith("State:"):
                            st = l.split(":", 1)[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
                        if st == "R":
                            copyfile("/proc/" + str(pid) + "/status", "status.txt")
                            print "copied"
                            pp.close()

                except Exception as ee:
                    print ee


th = MemoryThread()
th.start()
cmd = "/home/mursalin/Desktop/A"
cmd = cmd.split(" ")
path_stdout = "/home/mursalin/Desktop/stdout.txt"
path_stderr = "/home/mursalin/Desktop/stderr.txt"
path_stdin = "/home/mursalin/Desktop/inp.txt"
rp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=open(path_stdin, "r"), stdout=False, stderr=open(
    path_stderr, "w"), shell=False, preexec_fn=False)
rp.communicate()
br = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want the subprocess stay in zombie state, where you can collect the process status. But `subprocess.call` will auto collect zombie process, prevent the subprocess in zombie state.

So you should use lower api like `os.spawn` and `os.popen` to solve the problem.